# Function field is not working in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

In `purchase.order.line` I added new field `pln price` and changed unit price field to function:

```
'price_unit': fields.function(_amount_pln, string='Unit Price', required=True, digits_compute= dp.get_precision('Product Price')),
'plnprice': fields.float('PLN Price', digits_compute= dp.get_precision('PLN Price')),
```

Here is function:

```
def _amount_pln(self, cr, uid, ids, prop, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[line.id] = line.plnprice * 0.25
    return res
```

exchange value now is hardcoded, `0.25` as you see in `_amount_pln` function

Then I added new field in `purchase.order` class:

```
'exchange_value': fields.float('Exchange',readonly=False)
```

But how get this field value to my `_amount_pln` function I don't know.
can you please help me how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes function fields need the parameter: `store=True`

Try adding this parameter to your function field and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
def _amount_pln(self, cr, uid, ids, prop, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[line.id] = line.plnprice * line.order_id.exchange_value
    return res
```

order_id is many2one field in purchase order line in relation with purchase order, so you can easily access values of purchase order in purchase order line.

Answer (score 0):

Relation between "purchase.order" and "purchase.order.line" is "order_id". "purchase.order.line" contains "order_id". You can get values of "purchase.order" using this "order_id".

```
for purchase_line in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
    res[line.id] = purchase_line.plnprice * purchase_line.order_id.exchange_value
```