# Odoo IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: odoo

I just create a module. After adding values and got the problem IndexError: list assignment index out of range. How to fix it. Re Edit code please.
Here is my code:

```
class calculator(osv.osv):
    _name = 'calculator.calculator'
    def get_total(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
            res = []
            perfos = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context)
            for perfo in perfos:
                res[perfo.id] = perfo.p + perfo.b
            return res
    _columns = {
        'p':fields.selection(((1,'Outstanding'), (2,'Well Above Expectations'), (3,'As Expected'), (4,'Below Expectations'), (5,'VeryPoor'), (0,'N/A')),'title'),
        'b':fields.selection(((1,'Outstanding'), (2,'Well Above Expectations'), (3,'As Expected'), (4,'Below Expectations'), (5,'Very Poor'), (0,'N/A')),'title'),
        'total' : fields.function(get_total, method=True, string='Total Mark'),
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a dictionary of dictionary for functional fields. You defined `res` as list and tried to assign as the dictionary. `res[perfo.id]` is considered as list and index value `perfo.id` is not found in the `res` list. That is what the error says. Now the code will be

```
class calculator(osv.osv):
    _name = 'calculator.calculator'

    def get_total(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        res = {}
        for perfos in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
            res[perfos.id] = perfos.p + perfos.b
        return res

    _columns = {
        'p':fields.selection(((1,'Outstanding'), (2,'Well Above Expectations'), (3,'As Expected'), (4,'Below Expectations'), (5,'VeryPoor'), (0,'N/A')),'title'),
        'b':fields.selection(((1,'Outstanding'), (2,'Well Above Expectations'), (3,'As Expected'), (4,'Below Expectations'), (5,'Very Poor'), (0,'N/A')),'title'),
        'total' : fields.function(get_total, method=True, string='Total Mark'),
    }
```

For the above code you probably get this js error `Error: [_.sprintf] expecting number but found string`

I don't get the point adding up two selection fields. The key will get added up like 1+1 in a unicode format.

This following code will give you the basic idea of functional fields.

```
class calculator(osv.osv):
    _name = 'calculator.calculator'

    def get_total(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        res = {}
        for perfos in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
            res[perfos.id] = perfos.p + perfos.b
        return res

    _columns = {
        'p':fields.integer('A'),
        'b':fields.integer('B'),
        'total' : fields.function(get_total, method=True, string='Total Mark'),
        }
```

You may need to look at 
[How to set store trigger for computed fields in Odoo 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537608/how-to-set-store-trigger-for-computed-fields-in-odoo-8/29540600#29540600)

[Function field is not working in OpenERP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973329/function-field-is-not-working-in-openerp/29204596#29204596)

Comment: How can i give p value in calculator/p in form value? Now it looks like  Calculator / calculator.calculator,12

Comment: You may need to look at http://dirtyhandsphp.blogspot.in/2014/09/odooopenerp-recname-and-nameget.html

Comment: Bro please checkout the pic. I want to replace with calculator / firstfield. Please help me. [link](http://i.imgur.com/ixCUAyk.jpg)

Comment: For that you need to specify a `name` field or `_rec_name` or `name_get`. Without either one of those, you will always get `model.name,id`.